# Unnecessary rule consequence triggering from accumulate

Tags: drools

**Note: A better question is written about this topic. Please vote for this one to be closed.**

[Link to new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62705527/drools-accumulate-is-updating-an-irrelevant-fact)

I ran into a weird case which i'm trying to understand why it happens. The issue is where a rule is constantly triggering it's consequence for it's last fact, without anything related to it being changed. ***I should note that i am using drools 7.0.0***

## Behavior analysis

I have the following rules:

```
rule "TicketsBoughtPerClass"
when
    $ticketClass : TicketClass($customer : customer)
    accumulate(
        Ticket
        (
            customer != null,
            customer == $customer,
            ticketPrice >= $ticketClass.startPriceRange,
            ticketPrice <= $ticketClass.endPriceRange
        ); 
        $ticketCount : sum(1)
    )
then
    System.out.println("Total " + $ticketCount + " bought tickets for " + $ticketClass.getClassName());
    insertLogical(new TotalTicketsBoughtForClass($ticketClass, $ticketCount));
end

rule "TicketsNeededForBonus"
when
    $ticketClass : TicketClass($minTicketsNeededForBonus : minTicketsNeededForBonus)
    TotalTicketsBoughtForClass(ticketClass == $ticketClass, ticketCount < $minTicketsNeededForBonus, $ticketCount : ticketCount)
then
    //Do something based on ($minTicketsNeededForBonus - $ticketCount)
end
```

The idea is to count the number of `Ticket` objects that are within a price range of a `TicketClass` for a `Customer`. However, as i mentioned, regardless of the price of the `Ticket`, there is always a rule trigger for the last inserted fact.

I added `<- no match` for the triggers of interest.

Here is a sample output:

```
Ticket classes (inserting ticketClass facts): 
First class - Start price range: 200, End price range: 300
Second class - Start price range: 100, End price range: 199
Third class - Start price range: 50, End price range: 99

Buying tickets:
Bought ticket #0 for 60$ (insert)
Bought ticket #1 for 199$ (insert)
Bought ticket #2 for 250$ (insert)

Calling initial fireAllRules()
Total 1 bought tickets for Third class
Total 1 bought tickets for Second class
Total 1 bought tickets for First class

Changed ticket #0 from 60$ to 168$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class
Total 2 bought tickets for Second class

Changed ticket #0 from 168$ to 233$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
Total 1 bought tickets for Second class
Total 2 bought tickets for First class

Changed ticket #0 from 233$ to 230$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
Total 2 bought tickets for First class

Changed ticket #0 from 230$ to 283$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
Total 2 bought tickets for First class

Changed ticket #0 from 283$ to 167$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
Total 2 bought tickets for Second class
Total 1 bought tickets for First class

Changed ticket #0 from 167$ to 24$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
Total 1 bought tickets for Second class

Changed ticket #0 from 24$ to 1$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match

Changed ticket #0 from 1$ to 0$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match

Changed ticket #0 from 0$ to 8$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match

Changed ticket #0 from 8$ to 40$ (update)
fireAllRules() called
Total 0 bought tickets for Third class <- no match
```

Unless there is something i have misunderstood, this should not be the case.

## Debugging

I decided to dig in a little deeper into the drools core to get some answers myself. The search led me to the evaluation of the updated tuples in the accumulate node in `PhreakAccumulateNode.doRightUpdates`, which is where this additional trigger seems to be coming from. Just before the method `doRightUpdatesProcessChildren`, the following code is present:

```java
// if LeftTupleMemory is empty, there are no matches to modify
if ( leftTuple != null ) {
   if ( leftTuple.getStagedType() == LeftTuple.NONE ) {
         trgLeftTuples.addUpdate( leftTuple ); //<----
   }
   doRightUpdatesProcessChildren( ARGS );
}
```

In short, this code always adds the first left tuple that is in `AccmulateMemory` as being updated, even though it isn't, which is what causes the `RuleTerminalNode` to always fire it's consequence for this tuple.

My current dilemma is that I don't understand if this call for `trgLeftTuples.addUpdate( leftTuple )` is done on purpose, because when I took a look at the code in `PhreakJoinNode`, extremely similar code is present when processing the updated tuples, but this call is missing before `doRightUpdatesProcessChildren` is called.

**The main question i have about this if it is the expected behavior, and if so, why?**.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, and you want to eliminate rule triggering when there were found no single ticket for your rule, then you should add additional constraint.

```
rule "TicketsBoughtPerClass"
when
    $ticketClass : TicketClass($customer : customer)
    accumulate(
        Ticket
        (
            customer != null,
            customer == $customer,
            ticketPrice >= $ticketClass.startPriceRange,
            ticketPrice <= $ticketClass.endPriceRange
        );
        $ticketCount : sum(1);
        $ticketCount > 0
    )
then
    System.out.println("Total " + $ticketCount + " bought tickets for " + $ticketClass.getClass().getName());
end
```

Without `$ticketCount > 0` constraint, you have the only constraint for rule to be triggered `TicketClass()`

Comment: I didn't know that accumulates could have such conditions (or maybe I just forgot). Unfortunately, even though this would solve the additional triggering, I have additional rules that use `$ticketCount` via `insertLogical`, so I even need a sum of 0.

Comment: didn't got you, `$ticketCount` visibility is for the rule only, why are mentioning other rules? It is interesting to here about logical events (rare questions), do you have some to post? ;)

Comment: I updated the code snippet with the rule to reflect on what i'm talking about. Hopefully this makes a bit more sense :). I also intentionally didn't write anything in the then part of the second rule `TicketsNeededForBonus` so it's consistent with the example output i have provided