# Drools accumulate is updating an irrelevant fact

Tags: drools

When using an accumulate in Drools, a rule is evaluated and triggered for a fact that wasn’t updated.

Here is the rule:

```java
rule "WidgetsPerUser"
    when
        $user : User()
        accumulate(
            Widget ( checkIsUser($user) ); 
            $widgetCount : sum(1)
        )
    then
        System.out.println($user + " has " +  $widgetCount + " widgets");
end
```

The idea is simple: count the number of `Widget` objects per `User`. `checkIsUser()` is a simple equality check, but represents a check that cannot use indexing.

Here is sample output from Drools 7.0.0.Final:

```
-- Calling fire all rules --
User5 has 10 widgets
User4 has 10 widgets
User3 has 10 widgets
User2 has 10 widgets
User1 has 10 widgets

Widget moved from User3 to User1

-- Calling fire all rules --
User5 has 10 widgets
User3 has 9 widgets
User1 has 11 widgets
```

Here we have 5 `User` facts inserted into memory, and all have a starting `Widget` count of 10. The first call for `fireAllRules` displays the correct prints, as all `User` facts are inserted into memory. Next is an update, where a `Widget` is moved from User3 to User1. The expected output is present, however User5 has no reason to be displayed as being updated.

To visually highlight the issue:

```
User5 has 10 widgets    (User5 should NOT be triggered!)

                        (User4 is correctly ignored)

User3 has 9 widgets     (User3 is correctly triggered)

                        (User2 is correctly ignored)

User1 has 11 widgets    (User1 is correctly triggered)
```

The only way User5 differs from User2 or User4 is that it was the last user fact added, so why does it behave differently?

**Is this extra evaluation expected? What purpose does it serve?**

Note that the question is not about how to avoid or work around the extra trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around the drools core myself to get some answers. I found the following (in both versions 7.0.0 and 7.39.0):

In the method that evaluates the updates for the accumulate node `PhreakAccumulateNode.doRightUpdates`, just before the method `doRightUpdatesProcessChildren` (which is used for matching between left and right tuples), the following code is present:

```java
// if LeftTupleMemory is empty, there are no matches to modify
if ( leftTuple != null ) {
   if ( leftTuple.getStagedType() == LeftTuple.NONE ) {
         trgLeftTuples.addUpdate( leftTuple ); //<----
   }
   doRightUpdatesProcessChildren( ARGS );
}
```

Based on this, regardless of there being a match within the tuples in the memory, if there is an update of a fact that is part of an accumulate, the first left tuple (in this case User5) will always be treated as being matched.

I took a look at another beta node `JoinNode`. The code for that node is similar to the `AccumulateNode`, however it is missing this additional update of the first left tuple, leading me to believe that it is accidentally added, and has no reason to be present.

Am I correct with this?

Comment: Your analysis is 100% correct. I reported the problem here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-5488 and sent a pul request fixing it as you suggested https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/pull/2978 The fix will be available from Drools 7.41. If you'll find similar issues in future please feel free to open a ticket on our jira. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help!